# Ansible. Переподключение соединения в playbook

Tags: ansible

Создается сервер. Изначально есть пользователь **root**, его пароль и **ssh** на **22** порту (стандартно).

Есть написанный **playbook**, например, для react приложения.

При запуске **playbook**'a для него все разворачивается, но, перед развертыванием нужно минимально настроить сервер. Т.е. создать нового **sudo** пользователя, поменять **порт ssh** и копировать **ssh ключ** на сервер. Я думаю это нужно, наверное, для любого сервера.

После этой настройки в каталоге **host_vars** появляется **yaml** с переменными для этого сервера (*ansible_user, ansible_sudo_pass* и т.д)

Например есть 2 роли: **initial-server, deploy-react-app**.
И сам playbook (**main.yml**) для конкретного приложения:

```
- name: Deploy
  hosts: prod
  roles:
  - role: initial-server
  - role: deploy-react-app
```

Как сделать так, что бы при запуске `ansible-playbook main.yml` роль **initial-server** выполнялась от пользователя **root с его паролем**, а роль **deploy-react-app** от нового созданного пользователя и соединение было **по ssh ключу**, а не по паролю (root) ? Или это в принципе не правильный подход?

Comment: Ну лично я разделяю первоначальную настройку МОЕГО базового дистрибутива (как раз судо, ключи, прокси, репы) и собственно установку всяких веб серверов, бд и фаерфоксов. Т.е. есть `ansible-playbook base.yml` и `ansible-playbook someone-01.yml`. Это минимум экономит время, потому что каждый запуск ты не проверяешь тривиальные вещи. Да, "фрагментация" по плейбукам на +1, но тут, кмк решает нормальное название и описание.

Comment: А когда ты настроешь sshd "только по ключу" - как будешь выполнять роль `initial-server` в которой ssh всё ещё по паролю?

Comment: @donRumata , да, я тоже думал об этом. При создании нового сервера запускать его базовую "инициализацию", а потом уже раскатывать что нужно. Но интересно было, можно ли такое реализовать в одном плейбуке.
Сейчас написал скрипт (bash), который при запуске плейбука проверяет, есть ли настройки для этого хота (host_vars), и, если нет, запускает как-раз base.yml для первоначальной настроки. Запуск плейбуков всех теперь через него только что. Ну, посмотрим со временем, будет ли это удобно..

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, зачем обязательно переподключаться - ведь всё можно настроить в рамках той же сессии. Но если надо - вот тут интересное решение:
https://serverfault.com/questions/747604/how-can-i-have-ansible-restart-the-ssh-session-after-installing-nvm
использовать async.

Разбейте плейбук на три задачи: role initial-server,  потом примерно такой таск

```
- name: Kill open ssh sessions - ansible should log back in on next task
  shell: "ps -ef | grep sshd | grep `whoami` | awk '{print \"kill -9\", $2}' | sh"
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  when: nvm_installed | changed

- name: waiting for server to come back
  local_action: wait_for host={{ inventory_hostname }} state=started
```

и последняя роль deploy-react-app

Comment: Неплохой вариант, но как в таком случае быть с пользователем **root и его паролем** при первом запуске playbook'a ? т.е. **initial-server** запускается, допустим, так: **ansible-playbook initial-server.yml -u root -k**, а **deploy-react-app** так: **ansible-playbook deploy-react-app.yml**. Можно ли это каким либо образом решить в рамках одного playbook'a ?

Comment: Можно сделать чтобы подключение по ssh в ансибл было в виде сокета. тогда будет создаваться одно подключение и все будет выполняться в рамках одной сессии. 
Нужно в /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg расскомментировать или добавить строчку в раздел [ssh_connections] [ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s

аналогичные параметры можно указать в ~/.ssh/config 
почитайте про ControlMaster в ssh

Comment: для объединения плейбуков используйте include_role.